# Loading a regex string with escape characters from YAML

Tags: python, regex, yaml

I have seen some answers like this [Python interpreting a Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771163/python-interpreting-a-regex-from-a-yaml-config-file) but I am unable to use it to load a regex from a yaml file like this:

reg_ents.yaml

```
regex_sample: '\s*HEADER\d+\n'
```

When I attempt to load it from the code below:

```
import yaml
with open("reg_ents.yaml", 'r',encoding="utf-8") as yaml_instr:
    new_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yaml_instr)
    nregex = re.compile(new_yaml['regex_sample'],flags=re.I)
    print(nregex.findall("\nHEADER1\n"))
```

it returns an empty set `[]`. If you inspect `new_yaml['regex_sample']` you get this string:

```
\\s\*HEADER\\d\+\\n
```

I tried also using the yaml safe_loader modification:

```
import yaml
yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/regexp', lambda l, n: re.compile(l.construct_scalar(n),flags=re.I))
with open("reg_ents.yaml", 'r',encoding="utf-8") as yaml_instr:
    new_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yaml_instr)
    nregex = new_yaml['regex_sample']
    print(nregex.findall("\nHEADER1\n"))
```

but the output is still `[]` and the re.Pattern value still contains the double slashes. Any ideas? I have confirmed that if you use a standard approach (embedding within a .py file), it will work:

```
import re
test_regex = re.compile(r"\s*HEADER\d+\n",flags=re.I)
test_regex.findall("\nHEADER1\n")
```

This will output `['\nHEADER1\n']`

Comment: you use raw strings in Python, you need to escape the back slash in non-raw strings and thus also in the output/debugger of that string, depending of the file loader you have to escape the backslash also in the file, like in JSON strings

Comment: How do you do that in a YAML file?

Comment: it depends if the file format has raw strings or strings that interpret escape sequences, use the loader and use a debugger to see if the escapes are translated, for example `\n` and `\t`

Comment: I think that's part of the question. Can you use yaml to do that?

Comment: you can use any file format to get the strings you want it all depends how you need to write the strings in the file. it all depends what the file loader does with backslashes, experiment or read the file format definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The yaml_safe method above will work because you have not specified the string as raw. If you need to work with raw strings:

```
import re
def escape_ansi(line):
    ansi_escape =re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -\/]*[@-~]')
    return ansi_escape.sub('', line)
print escape_ansi(line = '\t\u001b[0;35mSomeText\u001b[0m\u001b[0;36m172.18.0.2\u001b[0m')
```

This will remove any escape items and convert it to a raw string.